# Setting the right distance to "="

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

Consider this expression:

[image]

How can I code this in LaTeX such that everything is aligned at the "=" sign *such that* the distance to the left and the right of the "=" sign at each line is the same as the distance to the other "=" which aren't in some separate column to which everything has to align to.

(Using for example `eqnarray` doesn't help, since in this case I can align everything at "=", but the distance to the left and the right is way off.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are perfectly correct in saying that `eqnarray` is not the right tool here.  The `amsmath` package provides several environments for displayed equations with correct spacing.  (Extra features are available from the `mathtools` package.)  In your example `align*` is the relevant construct to use (remove the `*` if you want equation numbers):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  x_1+x_2 &= (-p + i \sqrt{q-p^2}) + (-p - i \sqrt{q-p^2}) = - 2p,\\
  x_1\cdot x_2 &= (-p + i \sqrt{q-p^2}) \cdot (-p - i \sqrt{q-p^2})
  = (-p)^2 - (i \sqrt{q-p^2})^2 \\
  &= q.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Alignment points are specified by `&`, newlines by `\\`.

Comment: "`eqnarray` is no the right tool here" ... It's _never_ the right tool. `:)`